# Is there a way to constantly show my external IP address in the top unity bar?

Tags: unity, ip, system-tray

So the idea is to have it in the top right of the screen at all times. Thanks.

Comment: It's not impossible to implement it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Have you had a look at conky? Its a system monitoring tool that can display, amongst other things, the output of scripts. You could run a small script to scrape your IP from "whatsmyip.org" and display it at the top right of the screen. You can choose your font, colours, display an icon etc.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's 2 things: 1) Does it exist already to simply install and away you go and if not 2) How would you go about implementing this? I'm a Ubuntu noob if you can't already tell :)

Comment: Nice question, does your ip change over time? (i.o.w does it need to be dynamically read?). Can be done, but I am not home atm.

Comment: To the close voters: huh? how is this too broad?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I agree.  This is a simple to the point question.  I don't see this as too broad at all.  Might be multiple ways of doing it, but correct, not too broad at all.  =)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes my ip does change over time, so a check every 30 seconds would probably do it. I'm going to check out conky... will keep you posted! Thanks.

Comment: I just added an answer that doesn't use conky.  I only tested it on 14.04 though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from [this GitHub project](https://github.com/bovender/indicator-ip) here is a decent indicator that might help:

> ### Installation
>
> #### PPA and install
>
> `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bovender/bovender
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install indicator-ip`

This will install the program and configure automatic start at login. To run it right away, press
    ALT+F2 to open the Unity command prompt and enter `indicator-ip`.

Comment: Ok so this does EXACTLY what I wanted it to do - thank you!

Comment: Cool, this saves me from writing one :) (although we can dress it up a little haha)

Answer (score 2):

Try installing conky. It's an extremely configurable app that can be integrated into a desktop to show lots of information. There may be an extension out there for a section to pave onto a tool bar. http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html

Comment: A link to more information about conky would be helpful.